# How do I contanct Nikon Australia support?

Tags: nikon

I have a D600 with a [problem](http://www.imaging-resource.com/news/2014/02/25/nikon-d600-dust-problem-solved-owners-get-repair-they-have-been-waiting-for) and I want to contact Nikon Australia, Though Nikon NSW would be better. However, all emails bounce back and they don't seem to answer the phone.

I don't want to send my camera to the United States. Is there any contacts with Nikon that is closer?

**I tried these emails:**

- info@nikon.com
- support@nikon.com
- service.nau@nikon.com

Comment: Can you specify which e-mail addresses you have tried? Otherwise people might suggest answers you've already tried.

Answer (score 4):

Don't contact Nikon directly. Instead you should work through an authorised dealer or repair/maintenance facility. They'll handle the contact with Nikon, if needed.
And oh, if you bought the camera in the US, you're going to have to go through Nikon USA and a US based authorised dealer or repair facility as no other Nikon branch will accept equipment with US serial numbers for servicing.

Comment: I bought this camera on Europe. You think I'll have problem to repair ?

Comment: @Coelho check the terms of your warranty, if any. Probably not

Answer (score 4):

The Service & Repairs number for Nikon Australia Pty Ltd is **1300 401 200**

See [White Pages](http://www.whitepages.com.au/business-listing/nikon-australia-pty-ltd-873118) for further information.